# Importing products in CSV - URL Key already in use

Tags: magento2, csv, url-key

this seems to be a common problem and a flaw in vthe magento 2 CSV system, i want to export my catalogue update the pricing across all products and then re-upload it - however it requires a URL key change? is there any way to get around this?

thank you,

Chris

Comment: if you download the error report from csv importing, it will show you the rows with duplicated ulr_key. Basically you should correct those lines and then import agian and reindex the shop.

Comment: but there should be any - because what i have exported is correct???